# Slick 3.0 deleting many as transaction

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I have a bulk deleting of items from database but I want to do it as transaction. In that case I want all-or-nothing action which either deletes all items and returns successful response or returns error if one or more items are incorrect (non existing items in the DB etc.). At first I want to do simple check of existence of objects in the DB and if all of them exist I want to perform delete action or throw an exception otherwise.

Unfortunately I can't make things work correctly when doing that according to docs and responses found on Stack Overflow.

My action looks as follows:

```
def delete(siteIds: Long*): Future[Int] = {
    val filtered = sites.filter(_.id inSet siteIds)

    val action = (for {
      l <- filtered.length.result
      d <- l match {
        case c if c == siteIds.size => filtered.delete
        case _ => DBIO.failed(new InvalidEntityException)
      }
    } yield d) transactionally

    DB.run(action)
}
```

I also tried:

```
def delete(siteIds: Long*): Future[Int] = {
    val filtered = sites.filter(_.id inSet siteIds)

    val action = filtered.length.result.flatMap(l =>
      if (l == siteIds.size) {
        filtered.delete
      } else {
        DBIO.failed(new InvalidEntityException)
      }
    ) transactionally

    DB.run(action)
}
```

For some reason @DBIO.failure@ breaks the correct response. when I run that code, in case of incorrect data the exception is thrown but in case of correct data I get an error which says something (result?) is null.

```
[error]    null (Site.scala:174)
[error] models.SiteDao$$anonfun$22.apply(Site.scala:174)
[error] models.SiteDao$$anonfun$22.apply(Site.scala:171)
[error]    slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$$anonfun$runInContext$1.apply(DatabaseComponent.scala:146)
[error] slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$$anonfun$runInContext$1.apply(DatabaseComponent.scala:146)
```

How to make it work correctly?

Comment: You code is good I'm using a similar code and it works for me ! what's in line 174 of you SiteDao file ?

Comment: In the line 174 there is only `DBIO.failed(new InvalidEntityException)` statement.

Comment: This means to me that your code is throwing the exception event with correct data.

Comment: I know that, but I don't know why and how to fix it. When I comment out the `DBIO.failed` part the code works fine with the same data. If it's present it always fails. If I change it to `DBIO.successful(-1)` it also works fine in both correct and incorrect data cases. The problem obviously leis in `DBIO.failed`.

Comment: Your code is entering the else clause which means that what you qualify as correct data is not.

Comment: I would expect a failure if you have duplicates in `siteIds`. Try changing the the function like: `def delete(siteIdsInput: Long*): Future[Int] = {
  val siteIds = siteIdsInput.toSet // or .distinct
`